# VB.NET - How to add a large amount of events to a single handle?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

Recently I've been working on a program that has a few TextBoxes, CheckBoxes, ComboBoxes, etc., and I found that making one function handle multiple events is pretty simple, you just separate the events with a comma and the code recognizes the inidvidual events.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
    MsgBox("Hello World!")
End Sub
```

However, when you start to have a large number of events that you want handled by the same function, it gets a bit messy.

```
Private Sub Checks_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkInput1.CheckedChanged, chkInput2.CheckedChanged, chkInput3.CheckedChanged, chkInput4.CheckedChanged, checkInput5.CheckedChanged, chkOutput.CheckedChanged
    MsgBox("Checks Changed!")
End Sub
```

You can use the line continuation character `_` to make it look a little better.

```
Private Sub Checks_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
chkInput1.CheckedChanged, chkInput2.CheckedChanged, chkInput3.CheckedChanged, _
chkInput4.CheckedChanged, checkInput5.CheckedChanged, chkOutput.CheckedChanged
    MsgBox("Checks Changed!")
End Sub
```

But you still end up with a nasty block of text. Is there a more clean/concise way of doing this? What I have in mind is that it would be really nice to give an array of object events as an argument but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You can always wire up the events at runtime: `AddHandler chkInput1.CheckedChanged, AddressOf Checks_CheckedChanged`

Comment: Add the handlers in the Form's contructor (`Sub New()`). Note that the `sender` object can be cast to `CheckBox`. This will give you the control that raised the event. If the code in the handler is simple/short, you can also use a lambda (`Sub()`) as the delegate instead of `AddressOf`.

Comment: @Jimi I'm interested in your solution, but confused. By adding the handler to the constructor, how does that make it handle multiple events? Would you not still have to set which events are be handled by the function somehow?

Comment: In `Sub New()`, **after InitializeComponent()**: `For Each chkBox As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).ToArray() AddHandler chkBox.CheckedChanged, Sub() chkBox.BackColor = If(chkBox.Checked, Color.Red, Color.Green) Next`. Now, try to Check/Uncheck your CheckBoxes (here, direct child of the Form) as see what happens.

Comment: If you do the same thing **after** you have added some CheckBox object - in code - to the `Form.Controls` collection, the result is the same for all.

Comment: Not sure if I did something wrong, but it didn't seem to work. The checkboxes never changed color and the MsgBox I added never fired either: https://imgur.com/a/fDIaIvz

Comment: Do you have any CheckBox which is direct child of the Form? Apparently not, so you never enter the loop. If the CheckBoxes are inside a Panel, GroupBox etc, you need to specify `Me.Panel1.Controls`, for example, instead of `Me.Controls`.

Comment: Yes, it was a child of a TabPage. Now I understand how that works, thank you. Would you say that there is a benefit of using `New()` vs. `Form1_Load()` in this instance?

Comment: In practice, you'll have the same result. But you always want to keep your `Load()` handler proc as light as possible (not subscribed to? Better). There's also a catch with this event: it eats up exceptions. It will also slow down the rendering of the Form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by using the

```
AddHandler ObjectName.EventName, AddressOf EventHandlerName
```

syntax

It's simple enough to write a Sub that takes an array of object and loops over them to add the handler for each event.

For checkboxes:

```
Public Sub AddHandlerSub(PassedArray As CheckBox())
    For Each item As CheckBox in PassedArray
        AddHandler Item.CheckedChanged, AddressOf EventHandlerName
    next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you very much. I like this because it would work for controls added in the designer as well as dynamically added controls.

Comment: What about `removing those handlers`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ replace `AddHandler` with `RemoveHandler` and you have it.

Comment: It's also critically important if you want `RemoveHandler` to work to make sure you match the handler signature exactly (`Option Strict On` will guarantee this).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate the controls in the controls collection and not fuss with an array at all. You can also do further conditions if you want to exclude/add any given control, such as in the example of the TextBox Case in the following example.

```
Private Sub DataTables_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For Each Ctrl As Control In Panel1.Controls
        Select Case Ctrl.GetType
            Case GetType(CheckBox)
                AddHandler DirectCast(Ctrl, CheckBox).CheckedChanged, Sub(S As Object, EA As EventArgs)
                                                                          Dim ChkBox As CheckBox = DirectCast(S, CheckBox)
                                                                          'do something with ChkBox
                                                                      End Sub

            Case GetType(TextBox)

                Select Case Ctrl.Name
                    Case "TextBox1", "TextBox2" 'Add handle only to these contrls
                        'Or you could add Case Else and put the below handle within it
                        'Then this becomes an exclusion case
                        AddHandler DirectCast(Ctrl, TextBox).TextChanged, Sub(S As Object, EA As EventArgs)
                                                                              Dim TxtBox As TextBox = DirectCast(S, TextBox)
                                                                              'do something with TxtBox
                                                                          End Sub
                End Select

        End Select

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional Information: You can select procedures as Event Handlers by selecting the control. Then in the Properties window click the lightning bolt to display Events. Selected the event you wish to assign a handler and then the drop down arrow to the right. The resulting list will display all the Subs that match the signature of that event. Select the one you want and the designer will write or append the control to the Handles clause.

Add a procedure to the Form with a signature that matches the event.

```
Private Sub MultipleButtons(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

In the dropdown the list contains all Subs that match the signature of the event.

[image]

The designer writes the Handles clause

```
Private Sub MultipleButtons(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

End Sub
```